# Numpy Value Error: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, astropy

I am writing code in Python using numpy and astropy. In the code I wish to create random numpy arrays that generally resemble my data sets. Afterwards I would like to convert these randomized arrays of spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. Unfortunately I keep getting a value error, I am completely stumped on why this is happening I have tried to do some dummy tests such as if they are the same shape, all arrays have values that are reasonable and of the same type, etc. but I am stuck. here is my code:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u
import numpy as np 

R   = 445 + np.random.randn(262615) 
print(np.shape(R))
dec = 2 + np.random.randn(262615)
print(np.shape(dec))
ra  = 150 + np.random.randn(262615)
print(np.shape(ra))
c   = np.zeros(262615) 
print(np.shape(c))


for i in range(262615):
    c[i] = SkyCoord(ra=ra[i]*u.degree,dec=dec[i]*u.degree,distance=R[i]*u.mpc)
    print(c[i])
```

here is my error message:

```
PS C:\Users\sirep\Documents\C++ scripts> cd 'c:\Users\sirep\Documents\C++ scripts'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\sirep\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\sirep\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.5.0\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py' 'c:\Users\sirep\Documents\C++ scripts' '57764' '34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14' 'RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput' 'c:\Users\sirep\Documents\Python Scripts\sph2cart.py'
(262615,)
(262615,)
(262615,)
(262615,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sirep\Documents\Python Scripts\sph2cart.py", line 16, in <module>
    c[i] = SkyCoord(ra=ra[i]*u.degree,dec=dec[i]*u.degree,distance=R[i]*u.mpc)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: the error is telling you that you're trying to set an individual element with an array or sequence, what does `SkyCoord` return here? Is it a `tuple`?

Comment: I think I see where this code is going wrong now, SkyCoord returns 3 values x,y,z and I am assigning it to a single element of an array.

Comment: You declare `c` as an array of floats yet, you try to assign `c[i]` with `SkyCoord` object. Alternatively you can declare `c` with an empty list and use `c.append ` to populate it with `SkyCoord` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I should expand my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046537/numpy-value-error-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence#comment89121853_51047362) into a longer answer since a few things here deserve explanation and clarification for future readers.

In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51047362/982257) you wrote:

> I've figured out my error. SkyCoord returns 3 values an x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate. I was trying to assign three values to a single element of an array.

and that's certainly on the right track but not exactly.  In your original code you had something like:

```
c = np.zeros(262615)
```

This is already slightly asking for trouble since you didn't specify the data type, but by default the data type is `float64` which is probably what you want for many applications (certainly true for this one).  In any case, Numpy arrays, being typed, means that if you assign to a single element of the array like in your original code:

```
c[i] = SkyCoord(ra=ra[i]*u.degree,dec=dec[i]*u.degree,distance=R[i]*u.mpc)
```

the value you're assigning had better be a floating point number, or at least some other numeric type (like `int`) that can be unambiguously converted to float.  That's not true for `SkyCoord` since, as you noted, it's a multiplet of three dimensions.  My point is, in general if you're using Numpy arrays you want to be careful about what it's `dtype` is and what you're trying to assign to an element of it.  For more arbitrary objects you're more likely to get a slightly clearer error like:

```
>>> c[0] = object()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Still not great, but at least it demonstrates that it's trying to call `float()` to convert the argument to a float.  But you get a different result for `SkyCoord` since `SkyCoord` can be a container for an array of many coordinates, and Numpy sees that and instead tries to treat it like you're assigning a sequence of values into a scalar, which is the error you get.

Incidentally, it is also possible in Numpy to create more sophisticated array types using [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html).  This allows you to create an array of `(x, y, z)` coordinates for example like:

```
>>> c = np.zeros(262615, dtype=[('x', 'f8'), ('y', 'f8'), ('z', 'f8')])
>>> c
array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), ...,
       (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
>>> c[0]
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Although you can't assign a `SkyCoord` directly into one of these values (I think technically `SkyCoord` is treated as coordinate-free, regardless of what coordinate system you used to instantiate it, but I could be wrong about that), you can assign for example:

```
>>> c[0] = SkyCoord(ra=ra[i]*u.degree,dec=dec[i]*u.degree,distance=R[i]*u.mpc).cartesian.xyz
```

However, that's still not necessary because as I mentioned in my comment and explained further [in the docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/skycoord.html#array-operations) a `SkyCoord` can represent an array of coordinates like:

```
>>> coords = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree, distance=R*u.mpc)
```

and you can convert this all in one go to cartesian coordinates and retrieve separate arrays for the x, y, and z coordinates like:

```
>>> x, y, z = coords.cartesian.xyz
```

This has the added advantage that the coordinates are returned as `Quantity`s using the most appropriate length dimension (in this case Mpc since that's what you gave your distances in).  However, `coords.cartesian` itself is already effectively an array of `(x, y, z)` coordinates much like my structured array example above (technically it is not a Numpy array, but it has many of the same methods, can be converted to one like):

```
>>> coords.cartesian._values
array([(0.19718680211339326, 0.002173755110841713, 0.0021735811221131776),
       (0.6853033697941637, 0.005924402286034272, 0.004262079913938389),
       ...
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

but this is an undocumented internal attribute that should not be used (though I'm not sure why this interface isn't exposed as it could be useful...)

Finally, I'll add, using this interface is much, much faster, because all the loops are vectorized array operations mostly in C.  Any time you do things at the Python level such as assigning to an array (`c[i] = ...`) or attribute access (`c.cartesian.x.value`) you incur a significant performance penalty as values need to be converted from C to Python and back to C again.  Using vectorized operations avoids all that.  So when I make a `SkyCoord` array I get:

```
In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: c = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree, distance=R*u.mpc)
   ...: c.cartesian.xyz
   ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop
```

or 111ms for `262615` coordinates as in your original example.  Whereas doing it the "naïve" way gets me:

```
In [11]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in range(262615):
    ...:     c = SkyCoord(ra=ra[i]*u.degree,dec=dec[i]*u.degree,distance=R[i]*u.mpc)
    ...:     cx[i] = c.cartesian.x.value
    ...:     cy[i] = c.cartesian.y.value
    ...:     cz[i] = c.cartesian.z.value
    ...:

1 loop, best of 3: 18min 26s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I am relatively new to python, so the timing was a critical difference for me that definitely optimizes my code to a much higher degree.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my error. SkyCoord returns 3 values an x coordinate, y coordinate and z coordinate. I was trying to assign three values to a single element of an array. To fix it I had to first create 3 separate arrays for each coordinate, then ensure each value is dimensionless when inputting into their respective arrays:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u
import numpy as np 


R   = 445 + np.random.randn(262615) 
print(np.shape(R))
dec = 2 + np.random.randn(262615)
print(np.shape(dec))
ra  = 150 + np.random.randn(262615)
print(np.shape(ra))
cx   = np.zeros(262615) 
cy   = np.zeros(262615)
cz   = np.zeros(262615)
print(np.shape(cx))


for i in range(262):
    c = SkyCoord(ra=ra[i]*u.degree,dec=dec[i]*u.degree,distance=R[i]*u.mpc)
    cx[i] = c.cartesian.x.value
    cy[i] = c.cartesian.y.value
    cz[i] = c.cartesian.z.value
    print(cx[i],cy[i],cz[i])
```

Comment: The Python loop you're doing is extremely slow. `SkyCoord` works on arrays of coordinates directly:  `coords = SkyCoord(ra=ra*u.degree, dec=dec*u.degree, distance=R*u.mpc)`.  This is essentially a vector of sky coordinates.  `coords.cartesian` will give an array of the cartesian representation of the coordinates (as an array of `(x, y, z)` tuples).  If you want each coordinate as a separate array you can do `x, y, z = coords.cartesian.get_xyz()`.  You'll see that this returns `Quantities` which preserve the dimensions as well.